# Lombok - warning with @Data when equals and hashcode are implemented

Tags: java, jpa, lombok

I have JPA entity that extends other abstract class. I want to use @Data to avoid writing setters and getters but my equals and hashcode methods exists.

I get warning but I think I should not:

```
server\entity\User.java:20: warning: Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.
@Data
^
```

In my User class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    ....

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       ...
    }
}
```

When I add additionally @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) to @Data I get:

```
server\entity\User.java:21: warning: Not generating equals and hashCode: A method with one of those names already exists. (Either both or none of these methods will be generated).
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude but messages are pretty explicit here. What don't you understand?

Comment: @RC Message is "Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass". My understanding is that when methods are implemented there are not generated so this confuses me.

Comment: @RC. They're explicit, but the behavior seems to be wrong. When `equals` and `hashCode` are defined manually, `@Data` should just skip them without any warnings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`@Data` is a shortcut for `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter`,  `@Setter`, and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. Since you just want `@Getter`and  `@Setter`, why don't you just use them (this will avoid your exception or warning messages),

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable 
    ...

}
```

Comment: Good point, but still I'm wondering why @Data behave this way.

Comment: When Lombok comes across `@Data` annotation, it tries to implement `equals` and `hashCode`. During binary code injection by Lombok, the JVM complains as the `equals` and `hashCode` methods already exist in the class to be modified.

Comment: @KrzysztofKot And you're right and the explanation in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261314/lombok-warning-with-data-when-equals-and-hashcode-are-implemented#comment79495674_46261362) is wrong. It's a bug: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1078